# How to get response from firebase after set?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

```
function createGame(gameId, pin, currentDateTime, playerName)
{
  firebase.database().ref('games/' + gameId).set({
    pin: pin,
    createTime: currentDateTime,
    started: "0"
  });

  firebase.database().ref('games/' + gameId + '/players').set({
    id: "1",
    name: playerName,
    createTime: currentDateTime,
    status: "1"
  });
}
```

How to get response whether the **set** was successful or not in javascript? Please help I searched all over the internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation, [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) returns a promise that resolves or rejects when the operation completes.  This works just like any other promise in JavaScript.

For example:

```
  firebase.database().ref('games/' + gameId).set({
    pin: pin,
    createTime: currentDateTime,
    started: "0"
  })
  .then(() => {
    // success
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // error
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Worked Perfectly!